# xamarin.android app opens and closes immediately

Tags: logging, xamarin.android

i have an issue with a xamarin.android app created with visual studio: it builds correctly but, when i try to open it in my device, it asks for permissions (the first time) and then it closes immediately; the following times it opens and in less than half a second it closes.

when i execute it in debug mode i get this log, from the moment when i open it, to the moment when it closes:

```
W/GuiExt  ( 7717): Cannot find GuiExtService
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 7717): [unnamed-7717-1(this:0x829fe000,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:7717) connect(C): consumer=(7717:com.companyname.App4) controlledByApp=true
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 7717): [unnamed-7717-1] (this:0x829fe000,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:7717) setConsumerName: unnamed-7717-1
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 7717): [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-1] (this:0x829fe000,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:7717) setConsumerName: SurfaceTexture-0-7717-1
I/BufferQueueConsumer( 7717): [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-1 (this:0x829fe000,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) disconnect(C)
I/BufferQueue( 7717): [SurfaceTexture-0-7717-1](this:0x829fe000,id:1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
```

if someone could help me i'd be very thankfull.
tanks

Comment: Check the files you have recently changed you might have changed something crucial which might be throwing this.

Comment: Please upload a full `adb logcat` as it will have signals for when your application exits.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, but after some attempts, i found out that the problem was caused by an external package, so i avoided this issue using a whole different approach